# How to bind ObservableCollection<T> to SQL table? Is it Possible?

Tags: c#, sql

For example:

I have a class

```
MyClass //Dirty code
{
public int Id;
public string Name;
}
```

And I have a table in DB with Id and Name fields.
Can I bind ObservableCollection of MyClass objects to this DB table and how to do this?
Also I want to make changes in ObservableCollection and changes must be mirrored in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database does not automatically update your application if data changes and neither will it write back to the database if your application changes a value. The most basic approach to achieve what you are after would be to poll the server to check for changes at set intervals and update the screen from there.

If you are using SQL Server you could look into [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which would help identify what has changed if anything. None of this is automatic though and you will need to re-run your query each time and do the reverse to write back.

I assume you are using WPF / Silverlight so something like this could be used:

```
// Background timer used to refresh...
private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;

public MainViewModel()
{
    // Do initial load
    initializeload();

    // Start the timer to refresh every 100ms thereafter (change as required)
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Tick += Each_Tick;
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
    _timer.Start(); 
}

// Raised every time the timer goes off
private void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    // Refresh from database etc ...

    // Anything else you need ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use timers (cause tables too big). CDC, I think is something like a callback...

Comment: No, CDC is a set of tables that only lists records that have changed so reducing a million records down to only the records that have changed meaning you don't need to perform a full query each time.

Comment: Maybe SQL have function like callback to call my data provider when records changed?

Comment: I don't believe so. Normally it is down to the "client" (even if that is a server) to ask / inform the database. It is not the databases job to go off informing other processes that things have changed, that is not how they are designed. As I say, using CDC or some other task to do the heavy lifting is probably the best approach to your problem. Nothing will work out of the box.